# What was Big Narstie referencing?

Tags: big-fat-quiz-of-the-year

In Big Fat Quiz of the Year 2017, the contestant Big Narstie kept holding up his hands in a "heart" shape and kept saying something.  Jimmy Carr kept getting upset because what he was doing wasn't correct, but I was never able to quite catch what they were referencing.

What was Big Narstie referencing, and why was what he was doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He claimed it was the "Mo Farah sign". Also known as the [Mobot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxmpal.jpg), it is a celebration dance invented by sports commentator Clare Balding for British long-distance track athlete Mo Farah.

Here is the actual sign:

[image: Jimmy Carr and Mo Farah perform the Mobot]

Answer (score 3):

This [link](https://britishtelly.wordpress.com/2017/12/30/fun-and-games-big-fat-quiz-of-the-year-2017/) may help. It refers to your question.

> To Jimmy Carr’s chagrin, Mr. Narstie repeatedly made a heart shape with his hands and insisted on calling it the “Mo Farah sign” after the gesture made by the British distance runner to celebrate a win.

Watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klcdQjIpSnQ). Jimmy Carr and Big Narstie squabble over the meaning of the shape.